In HTML5, why does the `<source>` tag use the `src` attribute in `<video>` and `<audio>` elements, but it uses the `srcset` in a `<picture>` element?
I've been studying advanced HTML, and, I am wondering this: In HTML5, why does the <source> tag use the src attribute in <video> and <audio> elements, but it uses the srcset in the <picture> element? Why can't it always use src?

I don’t think srcset= existed back when <audio> and <video> were being defined.

At least as I read things, src is limited to a single target while srcset provides options based on the user's display.
It would, of course, have been possible for src to be used for both, but since the format differs it at least makes some sense.

I don't think the question is asking what the difference between them is, but rather why the choice for <picture> didn't match the one for <video> several years earlier, or why it uses the same element name for essentially disjoint purposes (<picture> and <video> operate very differently!). This is presumably documented somewhere in minutes or mailing list archives. "It would, of course, have been possible for src to be used for both" — but, would it? That depends on the rationale.

And my answer remains: "They (src and srcset) have somewhat different behavior, so different tags are appropriate", even if in most cases only one URL is going to be provided for an image, not taking advantage of the customizability.

Ideally an answer here would have primary-source design rationale (specification text, WHATWG minutes), but even without that an answer that doesn't address why <video> and <picture> differ is not really engaging with the question. That src and srcset have different formats is a given, but why isn't the design multiple single-source elements <source src="abc.png" ...><source src="def.webp" ...>, as is done for video/audio? Why doesn't video use srcset? You say different tags are appropriate, but they specifically didn't use different tags for this! Why not? You can [edit] your answer
